# Getting a URL with GtkClipboard

Tags: c, gtk, clipboard, gtk3

I'm trying to check if a url is on the system clipboard and if so get it from the clipboard. While reading the GTK API docs I came across `gtk_clipboard_wait_for_uris` but it seems to always return `NULL`:

```
g_print("%s", gtk_clipboard_wait_for_uris(gtk_clipboard_get(GDK_SELECTION_PRIMARY)));
```

What would be the correct/best way of getting a url from the clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait_for_uris` only works if the clipboard contains data tagged as a URI list (text/uri-list), e.g. when you perform a copy action in a file manager. It won't work as you expect if you copy a piece of text that just happens to contain a URI, e.g. "http://stackoverflow.com/". When you copy that string, it's most likely tagged as plaintext (text/plain).

The solution is to use `wait_for_text` and check whether it's a URI.